# Relu multilayer perceptron

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

could someone please help me to understand/correct the Relu multilayer perceptron/neural network/machine learning algorithm? I understand forward function, but I dont understand backward+update weights function. I dont know how to correct the mentioned functions. Thank you

```
import numpy as np

class MLP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_size = 2
        self.hidden_size = 4
        self.output_size = 1
        
        self.w1 = np.random.random((self.input_size, self.hidden_size))
        self.w2 = np.random.random((self.hidden_size, self.output_size))
        self.b1 = np.array([np.random.random() for TO in range(self.hidden_size)])
        self.b2 = np.array([np.random.random() for TO in range(self.output_size)])
        
        self.ITERS = 100
        self.LR = 0.1
        self.alpha = 0.01

    def predict(self, x, return_hidden_output=False):
        hidden_input = self.forward(x, self.w1, self.b1)
        hidden_output = self.relu(hidden_input)
        if return_hidden_output:
            return hidden_output
        output_input = self.forward(hidden_output, self.w2, self.b2)
        output = self.relu(output_input)
        return output

    def forward(self, l1, w, b):
        l2 = np.dot(l1, w) + b
        return l2

    def train(self, X, Y):
        for _ in range(self.ITERS):
            for x, y in zip(X, Y):
                self.backward(x, y)

    def backward(self, x, y):
        hidden_output = self.predict(x, return_hidden_output=True)
        pred = self.predict(x)
        
        output_error = 2 * (pred - y) 
        hidden_error = np.dot(output_error, self.w2.T)
        
        w2_grad = hidden_output.T * output_error
        h_grad = np.dot(hidden_output, hidden_error.T)
        w1_grad = np.outer(x, h_grad)
        
        self.update_weights(self.w2, self.b2, w2_grad)
        self.update_weights(self.w1, self.b1, w1_grad)

    def update_weights(self, w, b, error):
        print(error)
        for FROM in range(w.shape[0]):
            for TO in range(w.shape[1]):
                w[FROM][TO] -= self.LR * error[FROM]
                b[TO] -= self.LR * error[FROM]

    def relu(self, x):
        return np.where(x > 0, x, 0)

X = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1]
])
Y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

model = MLP()
model.train(X, Y)


a = model.predict([1, 0])
print("Prediction:", a)
```

I tried some ways to correct mentioned functions, but either got an out of bond error, or predicted values were wrong (etc. -3, or 0). Chatgpt havent helped me with this.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious error you are making is that you are not updating your biases which are learnable parameters just like the weights (the w's) of your network are. These need to be updated during back-propagation as well.

To shed some light on what is happening, during [back-propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) you start at the output of your network and compute your loss (a [mean-squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) in your case) from which you then apply the chain-rule of calculus to compute the gradient of your loss with respect to the learnable parameters (w's and b's in your case). The wikipedia entry I linked for back-propagation actually has an example that looks like [your small network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Finding_the_derivative_of_the_error) in which the derivation is shown.

For a more general treatment of the topic for larger networks with more hidden layers, [chapter 6 of the Deep Learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html)  by Ian Goodfellow (you can access it for free) provides a general derivation of gradient descent with matrices rather than scalar (as you are doing in your case). It works the same way except that the steps applied in algorithm 6.4 are based on [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) which might be unnecessary in your case but is how those things are actually implemented in practice (well in practice people use autograd libraries like PyTorch or TensorFlow which take care of the math for you but doing it the way you are doing is a good exercise to understand what is going on).

Finally a word of caution about chatGPT since you mentioned it. It can be dangerous to use a LLM to explain something you don't entirely understand, these models sometimes output nonsense and while they're extremely useful for helping you generate content, if you are looking for explanations of a topic it might be better to rely on articles written by humans who are knowledgeable on the topic rather than relying on a machine that paraphrases many such articles.